# Parallelization on cluster dask

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm looking for the best way to parallelize on a cluster the following problem. I have several files

- folder/file001.csv
- folder/file002.csv
- :
- folder/file100.csv

They are disjoints with respect to the `key` I want to use to groupby, that is if a set of keys is in `file1.csv` any of these keys has an item in any other files.

In one side I can just run

```
df = dd.read_csv("folder/*")
df.groupby("key").apply(f, meta=meta).compute(scheduler='processes')
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better/smarter way to do so in a sort of 
[delayed-groupby](https://github.com/TomAugspurger/dask-tutorial-pycon-2018/blob/master/solutions/01-delayed-groupby.py) way.

Every `filexxx.csv` fits in memory on a node. Given that every node has `n` cores it will be ideal use all of them. For every single file I can use this [hacky](http://blog.adeel.io/2016/11/06/parallelize-pandas-map-or-apply/) way

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

cores = mp.cpu_count() #Number of CPU cores on your system
partitions = cores #Define as many partitions as you want

def parallelize(data, func):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, partitions)
    pool = mp.Pool(cores)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

data = parallelize(data, f);
```

And, again, I'm not sure if there is an efficent dask way to do so.

Answer (score -1):

you could use a [`Client`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html?#api) (will run in multi process by default) and read your data with a certain `blocksize`. you can get the amount of workers (and number of cores per worker) with the [`ncores`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html?#api) method and then calculate the optimal `blocksize`.

however according to the [documantaion](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv) `blocksize` is by default "computed based on available physical memory and the number of cores."

so i think the best way to do it is a simple:

```
from distributed import Client
# if you run on a single machine just do: client = Client()
client = Client('cluster_scheduler_path')
ddf = dd.read_csv("folder/*")
```

**EDIT**: after that use `map_partitions` and do the gorupby for each partition:

```
# Note ddf is a dask dataframe and df is a pandas dataframe 
new_ddf = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.groupby("key").apply(f), meta=meta)
```

don't use `compute` because it will result in a single `pandas.dataframe`, instead use a `dask` [output](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html#api) method to keep the entire process parallel and larger then ram compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my question is pointing on another direction. In my situation the problem should be embarrassingly parallel and using `dask.dataframe` I guess I would have unneeded shuffling.

Comment: you could set the index as the `Key` column, then repartition it according to it values (with the `divisions` kwarg) and then use `map_partitions`. thus achieving complete parallel computing.

Comment: I'll try but I have the feeling that the `set_index` is going to be expensive.

Comment: it will, i had a similar situation and that's best i could think of.
however before you do so i suggest reading [this](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-performance.html)

Comment: I gave a try and it is very expensive. And my data is already nicely partitioned. This is way I was thinking to use `distributed` for every parquet file as in [this](https://github.com/TomAugspurger/dask-tutorial-pycon-2018/blob/master/01-dask.delayed.ipynb) Section 
Sequential code: Mean Departure Delay Per Airport

Comment: but you said the same `Key` can be in different `parquet` files. a simple `dask` `groupby` is parallel but it results in a single partition in the end (hence the slowness)  because it has no way of knowing in which partition a value that relates to each "group"  resides. if you will create your own map-reduce process using `distributed` you'll basically be doing the same thing as a `dask` `groupby`.

Comment: I said that The files are disjoints with respect to the `key`. So no `key` is on different files

Comment: ohh sorry, i misunderstood you.will edit in the answer .

Comment: I'll try your edit soon. I didn't know about the trick with output method.